# Выпадение нужного пункта меню в зависимости от расположения класса

Tags: javascript, html, css

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста с таким вопросом: на сайте есть меню, сделанное с помощью скрипта **ddaccordion.js**, нужно чтобы при расположении класса ***current*** раскрывался именно тот пункт меню, где указан этот класс (класс может перемещаться, в зависимости от страницы):

```
<div class="glossymenu">  
  <a class="menuitem submenuheader current" href="#">Петли</a>
  <div class="submenu">  
    <ul>  
      <li><a href="#">Стандартные</a></li>  
      <li><a href="#">Угловые</a></li>  
      <li><a href="#">Для стекла</a></li>  
      <li><a href="#">С доводчиком</a></li>  
    </ul>  
  </div>
  <a class="menuitem" href="#" >Напрвляющие</a>  
  <a class="menuitem  submenuheader" href="#" >Ручки</a>  
  <div class="submenu">  
    <ul>  
      <li><a href="#">Стандартные</a></li>  
      <li><a href="#">Угловые</a></li>  
      <li><a href="#">Для стекла</a></li>  
      <li><a href="#">С доводчиком</a></li> 
    </ul>  
  </div>
<a class="menuitem" href="#" >Ножки</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $('.glossymenu .current').click();
});
```

Попробуйте так.

Comment: Да, такой способ работает, а если расположение класса current например так: 

 <div class="glossymenu">  
   <a class="menuitem submenuheader" href="#">Петли</a>
   <div class="submenu">  
  <ul>  
    <li><a href="#" class="current">Стандартные</a></li>  
    <li><a href="#">Угловые</a></li>  
    <li><a href="#">Для стекла</a></li>  
  </ul>  
   </div>
   <a class="menuitem" href="#" >Напрвляющие</a>  
   <a class="menuitem" href="#" >Ножки</a>
 </div>

то как в такой ситуации быть, подскажите, если не трудно.

Comment: Тогда `$('.submenu').has('.current').prev().click();`

Comment: ling, Вы извините за мое незнание, последний вопрос. Как повязать эти два условия? 
Если current как в первом случае, то не выполняется второе и если current как во втором случае, то будет так как Вы написали $('.glossymenu .submenu').has('a.current').prev().click();.
Надеюсь Вы поняли меня.)

Comment: Тогда так.

    if($('.glossymenu .current').is('.submenuheader')){ (1) }
    else{ (2) }

Учите [ТТХ][1]. =)
[1]: http://api.jqueru.com

Comment: Очень Вам благодарен за помощь и за пожелание спасибо, учту.